# Is HTTP supported by OpenDJ 2.5.0 Express version?

Tags: opendj

I can't find the HTTP connection handler in OpenDj 2.5.0 express version.
Is is supported? Also is DSML supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP REST to LDAP interface was added in OpenDJ 2.6.0, and thus is not part of 2.5.0-Xpress.
OpenDJ also has a DSML gateway which is available as a separate download.
Regards,
Ludovic

Comment: Ludovic, You can say I have a silly question. I am trying to follow the instructions in http://wiki.ihris.org/wiki/Installing_OpenDJ_On_Ubuntu but now as 2.6 is more recent version with subscription i have changed my wget to wget http://backstage.forgerock.com/downloads/enterprise/opendj/2.6.0/OpenDJ-2.6.0.zip which does gets me the zip file but then the command line to unzip is giving error complaining that end-of-central-directory not found . Either this is not a zip file or it constitutes one disc of the multipart archive. ubuntu machine where this is getting installed only cli based machin

Comment: i am using wget --username=** --ask-password https://https://backstage.forgerock.com/downloads/enterprise/opendj/2.6.0/OpenDJ-2.6.0.zip , not much progress still

Comment: I think i getting a sense that community users can only use 2.5 as the link https://forgerock.org/downloads/opendj-archive/ lists OpenDJ 2.5.0-Xpress1 as the latest which can be used by community users by cli and as per the site OpenDJ 2.5.0-Xpress1  is in end of service life thus should not be used

Comment: checked the size of the download. wget is not getting the zip as the size of the file is much smaller than expected